# PostgreSQL. Получить дерево сущностей

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица неких сущностей, которые могут быть вложены друг в друга:

```
id  | parent_id | name
-------------------------------------------------
1   | 0         | Некая сущность
2   | 1         | Сущность вложена в сущность 1
3   | 1         | Сущность вложена в сущность 1
4   | 2         | Сущность вложена в сущность 2
5   | 0         | Сторонняя сущность. Не должна присутствовать в выборке
```

Мне необходимо вытащить сущность и всех ее потомков(в том числе не прямых).
Задача решается довольно легко, можно в коде перебором(рекурсией) получать потомков для каждой сущности, пока они не кончатся. Но мне видится такое решение не очень эффективным.
Возможно ли получить дерево сущностей единым запросом? Более эффективным, чем кучка запросов из кода.

Comment: Связи один ко многим лучше выносить в отдельную табличку

Comment: @Darth Впервые такое слышу. Есть аргументы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как раз для этого и существуют [рекурсивные запросы](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.5/queries-with):

```
with recursive r as (
    select
      id, parent_id, name
    from some_table
    where parent_id = 1
  union
    select
      st.id, st.parent_id, st.name
    from some_table as st
    join r
      on st.parent_id = r.id
)
select id, name from r;
```

Comment: То, что нужно! Благодарю.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: 2 минуты еще. Ждем)

Comment: Кстати, `where parent_id = 1` должно быть `where id = 1`, иначе самая верхняя сущность не выберется