# Иерархический запрос с загадкой

Tags: sql, алгоритм, postgresql

Есть таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Id  Parent_id   Title   Type_id
1   NULL    Россия  1
2   1      Московская область   2
3   2         Балашиха  3
4   2         Дмитров   3
5   2         Красногорск   3
6   1     Новгородская область  2
7   6         Чудово    3
8   6         Валдай    3
9   NULL    США 1
10  9      Алабама  2
11  10        Бирмингем 3
12  10        Флоренс   3
13  10        Гувер 3
14  9      Калифорния   2
15  14         Лос-Анджелес 3
16  14         Окленд   3
```

Рекурсивный запрос

Есть 3 типа описания столбца "Title":
1. Страна (Type_id = 1);
2. Область / Штат (Type_id = 2)
3. Город (Type_id = 3)

Нужно каким-то образом извлечь все те города, которые относятся к стране.
Например, выбрали "Красногорск", то результат должен вывести все города:
Балашиха, Дмитров, Красногорск, Чудово, Валдай.

Есть мысль как сделать:

Parent_Id зависит от Id.

Красногорск (Type_id = 3) имеет Parent_id = 2. Исходя из этого уже смотрим на строку под этим Id = 2: Московская область (Type_id = 2), исходя из этого ищем уже строку с Id = 1: Россия (Type_id = 1). И если ParentId IS NULL, тогда прекратить поиск и вывести полный список городов России.

Не могу представить как это реализовать.

Подскажите пожалуйста, спасибо.

---

Ситуация №1:
Ввод: 8
Вывод: Балашиха, Дмитров, Красногорск, Чудово, Валдай.

Ситуация №2:
Ввод: 15
Вывод: Бирмингем, Флоренс, Гувер, Лос-Анджелес, Окленд

Более понятно, что должно получиться.

Comment: А в чем суть задачи то ?? Для чего вам такой вывод ?? Обычно делают вывод с подгрузкой поочередной. Сначала страны потом выводится страна после выбора страны отправляется запрос выводится регион или же город если регион пропустить.

Comment: Суть в том, чтобы вывести все города, которые принадлежат той стране, id страны которой мы укажем сами. При выборе id = 5 мы получим результат: Балашиха, Дмитров, Красногорск, Чудово, Валдай.

Если же указать, например, id = 12, то будет выведено:

Бирмингем, Флоренс, Гувер, Лос-Анджелес, Окленд

Comment: А в чем загадка, если вы сами уже назвали основное слово для поиска информации по таким запросам "рекурсивный". Да, в postgresql есть рекурсивные запросы. Например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706604/postgresql-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9/706608#706608 И еще масса примеров: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+recursive

Comment: Я с утра по настоящее время пытаюсь запрос составить, вообще ничего не получается, либо выводит просто город по указанному id, либо просто страны.

Comment: Ну я вот пример привел, там только поле name заменить на title и он выведет все для страны с id=1

Comment: А если мне нужно автоматически получить id страны, я могу выбрать город из США, тогда не получиться вывести города.

Comment: Ну вообще получиться, если вместо обычного select в конце написать еще один рекурсивный запрос для движения в обратном направлении.

Comment: Ситуация №1:
Ввод: 8
Вывод: Балашиха, Дмитров, Красногорск, Чудово, Валдай. Ситуация №2:
Ввод: 15
Вывод: Бирмингем, Флоренс, Гувер, Лос-Анджелес, Окленд Более понятно, что должно получиться.

Comment: И почему картинкой то таблица, думаете мне сейчас хочется набивать контрольный пример с этой картинки, что бы запрос написать ?

Comment: Читал документацию, но, что если мне нужно начинаться отсчитывать данные не с конца (!последнего города), а где нибудь в середине? Если укажу город с id = 8, возможно обратный счет сработает. Если с 7 начинать, тогда не захватит id = 8. Слишком сложно думаю я скорее всего, как-то проще это можно сделать, но, как я писал, без догадок.

Comment: Прошу прощения за изображение, не знал, что можно как-то на форум поместить таблицу. Сейчас сделаю. :c

Comment: Обновил ответ думаю подойдет для данного варианта.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS country_info(id serial PRIMARY KEY, Parent_id INT, Title varchar(49), Type_id INT NOT NULL) - данная таблица.
Данные не через INSERT INTO создавались -_- Очень сложно на таких форумах следить за сообщениями, первый раз спрашиваю, спасибо всем большое что так быстро отвечаете...

Comment: Если уровней всего 3, то можно и без рекурсии обойтись...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут потребуется двойной рекурсивный запрос, один из которых поднимется вверх по дереву (CTE "Up"), а другой опять спустится (CTE "Down"):

```
with Recursive Up as(
    select id, parent_id
      from Tab where id=8
     union all
    select T.id, T.parent_id
      from Tab T join Up on T.id=Up.parent_id
),
Down as(
    select id, parent_id, NULL::varchar(20) as Title, NULL::int as type_id
      from Up
     where parent_id is null
     union all
    select T.id, T.parent_id, T.title, T.type_id
      from Tab T join Down on T.parent_id=Down.id
) 
select * from Down
 where type_id=3
```

В "Down" у полей Title и type_id проставьте типы, соответствующие объявлению в таблице.

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c2793/1)

Более короткий, но более хитрый и сложный для понимания вариант:

```
with Recursive RCTE as(
    select id, parent_id, Title, type_id, 1 as Vector
      from country_info where id=8
     union all
    select T.id, T.parent_id, T.title, T.type_id,
           case when T.parent_id is null then 0 else RCTE.Vector end
      from RCTE
      join country_info T
        on (RCTE.vector=1 and RCTE.parent_id=T.id)
        or (RCTE.vector=0 and T.parent_id=RCTE.id)
) 
select *
  from RCTE
 where vector=0 and type_id=3
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/61ab5/1)

в данном случае мы используем одну и ту же рекурсию и что бы подняться по дереву и что бы спуститься. Поле Vector показывает текущее направление движения. Если оно 1 (которая стоит в затравочной части рекурсии), то идем вверх. Когда дошли до корня, по условию T.parent_id is null переключаем Vector в 0, при этом на следующей итерации рекурсии условие соединения сменится на обратное и поиск пойдет вниз.

Comment: Отличный вариант решения )) Я лайк поставил )) Свой запрос тоже откорректировал теперь тоже работает ))

Comment: Господи. Спасибо вам и всем остальным за помощь. Все работает так как я хотел. Не могу выразить благодарности, спасибо ещё раз.

Answer (score 0):

Тогда можно вот так сделать

```
SELECT * FROM Tab WHERE Parent_Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Tab WHERE Parent_Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Tab WHERE Id IN (SELECT Parent_Id FROM Tab WHERE Id IN (SELECT Parent_Id FROM Tab WHERE Id = '8'))))
```

Но я бы не делал такой длинный запрос с кучей вложенностей а выбрал все поля создал бы многомерный массив и перебирал бы уже циклом.

Comment: Там 3 уровня вложенности и вообще может быть больше

Comment: @Mike ну он же пишет что страна уже выбрана получается по стране нужно выбрать все города независимо от области я так задачу понял. решение такой задачи я написал.

Comment: Страна не выбрана, прошу прощения. Мы исходим из города, id которого вводит пользователь. А далее уже в обратном порядке выбираем все города связанные с этим городом, то есть в США не лезем, а только выбираем города которые находятся между Россией и США

Comment: @AgentMax если вы точно знаете кол-во вложенности то в обратном порядке такой же запрос использовать можно

Comment: @AgentMax Вот, теперь я кажется начал понимать в чем ваша проблема, вам надо сначала подняться по дереву вверх, а потом опускаться вниз. Тогда вопрос, всегда ли начинают именно с города, а например не с области и всегда ли надо двигаться до самого корня и выводить потом все объекты от полученной точки корня ?

Comment: Именно с города. На вводе город, на выводе список городов данной страны. Сначала вверх, потом вниз. Все верно. :)

Comment: @AgentMax ну я же обновил ответ. добавил второй вариант так же с лесенкой сначала вверх потом вниз

Comment: Запрос alexsis20102, помоему работает, но немного не так. При вводе, например id 4 - не выводит ничего, но если ввести на id-1 то выводит то что нужно.

Comment: @alexsis20102, вывод, как я понял идет от ParentId. Когда указываю ParentId, которые относятся к нужным городам, то выводит нормально, но вывод нужен именно с Id, а не с ParentId, хотя исходя из вашего кода так и есть, я запутался :(

Comment: @AgentMax по идее моя версия запроса должна работать. Вам Mike написал решение с примером наглядным. ))

Comment: @AgentMax да в моем запросе была ошибка. Я отредактировал ответ и запрос теперь 100% рабочий.